# Twilio, how do you handle maxParticipants in a conference?

Tags: c#, twilio, webhooks, twilio-api

I've been looking at the Twilio documentation and online to find out how the `maxParticipants` Conference TwiML parameter works. It says you can specify a number less or equal to 250 and that's pretty much it.

> This attribute indicates the maximum number of participants you want to allow within a named conference room. The maximum number of participants is 250.
> https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-maxParticipants

What happens if you exceed this amount?

> **53107: MaxParticipants is out of range**
>
> Set the MaximumParticipants value from 1 up to the maximum allowed for the Room Type.
> https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/53107

It seems like this error is thrown.

We want to give two types of users different limits to the same conference. Basically we want to ensure that up to 20 super users can always get access. We're concerned that too many ordinary users will join and lock out the super users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use maxParticipants to provide a sub-set of user type a maximum.

The first person to actually create the conference room (first person to dial in) sets the parameter for maxParticipants.

I had one DID X I used for two callers to call into the same conference room, using maxParticipants="2"
I had another DID Y I used for one of the callers to call into the same conference room, using maxParticipants="3"

If a participant dialed in with DID X and was the first person to dial in, that set the maxParticipants for everyone, the DID Y person could not join if there were already 2 DID X people on the call. Even if the DID X party that started the conference hangs up, the maxParticipants is still set to the value originally used to create the conference (which was 2).

If the participant dialed in with DID Y as they were the first participant to dial in, than maxParticipants was set to 3 for the call, even when they drop.

Comment: Thanks what does DID stand for ?

Comment: Ahhh https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-direct-inward-dialing-did direct inward dialing